# Does a Ben Noach, who keeps the seven mitzvot but has bad hashkafah, get punished by Hashem?

Tags: hashkafah-philosophy, gentiles, reward-punishment, noahidism, apostasy

Does a Ben Noach, who keeps the seven mitzvot but has bad Hashkafah, get punished by Hashem?

For example, if the B'nei Noach says things that are kefira for a Jew like saying that the Oral Torah  is not from Hashem or saying that there will be no resurrection of the dead. Is that Kefirah for a Ben Noach as well?

Comment: As a rule, we don't have much information on the afterlife judgment criteria for either Jews or gentiles. You better rephrase the question to whether Gentiles are commanded on Hashkafa. The answer is "formally not". The 7 laws do not include Hashkafa at all, they don't have to believe in Hashem in the first place either. BUT, as you know 2 Jews 3 opinions. So some other Rabbis do feel that Gentiles have to have some basic beliefs.

Comment: @AlBerko As I understand it, Gentiles have to believe that there is a single G-d. I.e., I think it is phrased more in terms of the negative than the positive. I don' t think they necessarily have to believe in the attributes of G-d such as omnipotence, etc. Perhaps, they can be atheists too, but that would make them fools.

Comment: @AlBerko Well - my assumption is wrong according to one opinion. See https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/18635/5275.

Comment: This may partially answer your question - https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/65751/5275

Comment: No, No and No. 1. All Jews are entitled to the WTC (last Mishna of Sanhedrin),   just differ in the amount of punishment, so to say. 2. besides Dinim (obligation to establish a legal system) all 6 Noahide Laws are Don'ts, not Do's, so they are warned on idolatry but have no (strict) obligation on believing in G-d. 3. THe Noahide Laws are a mess, as we don't have a clear tradition on this - some say they're not limited to 7 there are much more, some say believe in G-d is a flipside of idolatry etc.

Comment: As you see, there's no clear list in the Torah, only the Sages try to figure it out some 3500 years after Adam was commanded. Isn't it strange?

Comment: also related and partial answer: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/18628/11501